# Dynamic Thread Pooling with the GPU

Tags: c#, multithreading, opencl

So far I have implemented a simple programm with a thread pool paradigm, 
in which I have a number of threads working on a number of tasks.
All tasks available at a time are independant from each other.
For each task, I will have some output and usually a number of tasks generated from it. (e.g

`func(a, b):
    tasks.enque((a+b, b+1), (a*b, b+2));
    return sin(a);`

In reality there may be a lot more tasks, generated for each task that is finished, so the workload grows pretty fast.
In order to keep the computing time reasonably low, I thought I might generate the tree using the GPU, for the tasks are independant, as soon as they are created.

And with this I come to my question: Is there the posibility to do this somehow straigth forward e.g. using OpenCL?
I wonder if it is a good idea. So far I haven't seen a possibility to add tasks to a queue dynamically in OpenCL, and if I'd say:
Ok - first I calculate the first queue, and generate a new queue, which I start later again, I fear that the overhead for memory copying between the GPU and the CPU might be so large that it won't be efficient anymore for the simple calculations I intend to do.
I am not sure, if I am able to keep the data in the GPUs RAM, or if it is extracted automatically, and therefore needs to be copied there and back again.
(I plan to use OpenCL.net)

Thank you for enlightning me with your knowledge,
for I am a absolutly beginner with both, Multithreading and GPUs

Comment: Having never done any SMP what makes you think it is a good idea to learn Heterogeneous computing? The overhead of copying data from managed C# over to the GPU is INSANE. You only really gain something if you have a deep pipeline with lots of SIMD. But given that you don't have any experience in SMP I doubt you know what SIMD means.

Comment: That is exactly the question, how can I achieve this deep pipeline.
It is some kind of SIMD. Ok it is Two Instructions (Multiplication and Addition) and this shall be performed on all data.
But instead of copying it back, I also want to perform the very same task again on the result, until som threshhold is met (either the memory is full, or some time or depth threshold which is predefind is met).
The  idea is, to calculate the length of all paths between N waypoints, that I either can calculate in some given time, or that use at max M hops.

Comment: I need two calculations there: once the cost for each path is determined by multiplication of the costs between each waypoint, and the other by summing up. You can go there and back again, each time.

Comment: Your current method is SISD, look up SIMD and rewrite your method signiture appropriately. However even then, you really are not ready to learn OpenCL. You have no experience in thread synchronization, nor marshaling of data nor threading, nor native/managed interop nor native/device interop...

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I have no experience with it at all, but I thought, the step before experience is learning, so I hoped I might start with this, and might find a helping hand here. So I will try to post some approach I have in mind, tomorrow and hope you'll be as patient with me as to help me to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: I applaud you for wanting to learn...but you are trying to learn to "juggle with chainsaws on a unicycle, blindfolded", before you learnt to walk. You should learn to juggle, first, then learn to unicycle, then learn to juggle chainsaws...etc...

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenCL 2.0 it is possible to enqueue kernels from the device without host interaction. 
Have a look at [OpenCL™ 2.0: Device Enqueue and Workgroup Built-in Functions](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/11/17/opencl-2-0-device-enqueue/).

However I doubt you will find .Net bindings for OpenCL 2.0, as far as I'm aware there aren't still C++ bindings.

Comment: Looks interesting.The problem is, my computer, and the computers in my university all have NVIDEA Graphics, and it seems, OpenCL2.0 is not available to them, as of now.

Comment: On Nvidia is max OpenCL 1.2, AMD and Intel support OpenCL 2.0 on GPU and CPU.

Comment: C++ bindings would be impossible. Interop without knowing what compiler/version you are using is only possible in C.

Comment: @Aron I'm not sure what you are talking about. OpenCL 1.2 C++ bindings are available for download on Khronos website, OpenCL 2.0 C++ bindings should be available in the future.

Comment: Wait... Are these source files or binaries?

Comment: 1.2 C++ is just [one header file](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl.hpp)